# Angular2 not working with prototype.js

Tags: angular, prototypejs

I am trying to set up Angular2 in an existing application which uses prototype.js. But looks like Angular2 also has dependency on prortotype.js (correct me if I am wrong) and hence throws a ***`"maximum call stack size exceeded RangeError(in Chrome)"`*** when trying to load the app. I am pretty new to Angular2.

I could reproduce it in the Angular2 quick-starter app by adding the prototype.js dependency.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>


    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.3/prototype.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

The partial stack trace in the web inspector console is:

> Error: (SystemJS) Maximum call stack size exceeded RangeError: Maximum
>   call stack size exceeded at ParamDecoratorFactory
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:401:39)
>   at new 
>   (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.3/prototype.js:214:23)
>   at ParamDecoratorFactory

I am doing something wrong? or if not, is there a work around for it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the file for `prototype.js`.

Add

`var bindTemp = Function.prototype.bind;`

at the beginning of the file.

Add

`Function.prototype.bind = bindTemp;`

at the end of the file.
It should work now.

Credits: [Solution](http://tooschee.com/magento-prototype-vs-angular-conflict-problem/)

Comment: Is there a fix for this but on the angular side and not to prototype.js?